# drag & DROP with scroll for touch devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, touch, multi-touch

I am looking for a drag & DROP plugin that works on touch devices(I found a few working well).
But I have a div with scrollable content inside and this plugins disable scroll.
Any ideas how to fix having scroll and drag & DROP in the same div for touch devices?

Answer (score 1):

I use jQuery Touch Punch myself. Check it out: [jQuery Touch-Punch](http://touchpunch.furf.com) I use it on my ipad for sortable lists and it responds well to scrolling.